# Websphere 9 - cannot create profile and no error shows up in Wizard

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

[image]

I'm in this page in the profile creation wizard, but nothing happens when I click the next button. It wont proceed to the next page. No error shows up too. weird.

I already have an existing WAS 8.5 installed in my machine so I figured this may be due to port conflict but the ports above have already been recommended by the wizard.  What seems to be the problem here? Uninstalling my existing WAS 8.5 is not an option since I still use it .

I need help. Anyone? :-)

Comment: Try to create profile from the command line, using manageprofiles.bat tool. Maybe you have some issues with graphical interface.

Answer (score 3):

You have to **"Run as Administrator"** when starting profile creation wizard. Otherwise, you cannot go to the next step.

Comment: This solved it for me.  Do a ctrl+shift+click when opening the program and it will run as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

You go to path where you install WebSphere, for example.

```
   C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin\ProfileManagement
  -> Search file pmt.bat.
```

Run it with administrator permision. And setup again

Answer (score -1):

Assumed you need WebSphere for dev purposes. I would recommend run WAS in docker.

**There is a official docker image for WebSphere covered versions from 8.5 https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/websphere-traditional/**

E.g. run websphere with default profile:

```
docker run --name was -h was -p 9043:9043 -p 9080:9080 -d \ 
ibmcom/websphere-traditional:profile
```

Comment: What is wrong with the answer? Ok, it does not answer question directly, but it solves problem in the nutshell - installing multiple WAS on same machine in much better way. Installation and run WAS in one step! Better abstraction, better maintainability and easier setup against to classic approach! Think out of the box and use docker :)